# Warning message when starting orion from image

Tags: fiware-orion, filab

I've just installed orion-psb-image-R3.3 using the image available @Fi-Lab. When I start the orion instance, I get a message telling that there is some problem with the contextBroker.pid:

*" Starting contextBroker...                         cat: /var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid: No existe el fichero o el directorio"*

Despite this message, the context broker starts properly. I've just deployed a new machine with the aforementioned image, is there anything I need to do before /etc/init.d/contextBroker start.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This 'error message' is harmless.
At starting the broker, a check is made to see whether a broker is already running (and for that the pid-file is needed). As the pid file doesn't exist, this unfortunate message pops up. We are working on improving the start/stop script, to be included probably in our next release (0.13.0).